# I have authenticated via Azure ADAL without issues. what next?

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, azure-active-directory

*Newbie alert*

I have successfully configured ADAL authentication using python code.

I have used the following code:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/website_sample.py

So I am now able  to log in to the app configured in my azure account and retrieve the access token, refresh token Etc.

Next

I have an application that has user role based permitted actions.

Upon successful login in Azure, the App must check the user role and open the pages based on the user's role.

I used React JS and Python to build my app.

Now i am clueless as to how to integrate my user roles with the app.

Can anyone of you suggest any reading materials or solutions to this?

Thank you.

I have read about ADAL authentication but did not find process to post authentication.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/website_sample.py

I want any architecture plan or sample code in python/ JS where the token from ADAL authentication is retrieved and used  to login to the application..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement RBAC using Azure AD's Application Roles & Role Claims feature or using Azure AD Groups and Group Claims. You can add roles using the manifest in Azure AD and also in the app itself.

This is by far the best sample and guide for adding RBAC and using ADAL. I was able to get a working sample going quickly from this.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims